# Same function on multiple elements

Tags: c#, arrays, unity-game-engine

Suppose that I want to use the same function on multiple array elements:

```cs
public gameobject[] LockPIButton;

LockPIButton[0].SetActive(false);
LockPIButton[1].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[2].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[3].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[4].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[5].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[6].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[7].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[8].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[9].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[10].SetActive(true);
LockPIButton[11].SetActive(true);
```

Is there a possible way to apply the same function to multiple elements without copy-pasting it?

Comment: Is it supposed to be `false` on one of them?

Comment: @derHugo yeah, I need to make an exception on one or few of them

Comment: One or few ... you would need to be a bit more specific ;) And if a few then on what condition?

Answer (score 4):

In general, you can use any kind of loop, for instance a `foreach`.

(for clarity I added a "s" for plural to the name of the array field)

```
public GameObject[] LockPIButtons;

// ....

foreach (var lockPIButton in LockPIButtons)
{
    lockPIButton.SetActive(true);
}
```

Or use the equivalent `ForEach` method:

```
LockPIButtons.ForEach(lockPIButton => lockPIButton.SetActive(true));
```

---

However, since you depend on the index to set one of them to false you could:

- Use a classic `for` loop, see [derHugo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63808690/479251)
- simply set back the one you want to false afterwards (though it feels like a waste of processing time):

```
// set all active first, then
LockPIButton[0].SetActive(false);
```

- use linq's `Select` that can take the index as an additional lambda parameter:

```
LockPIButtons.Select((button, i) => button.SetActive(i != 0))
```

Answer (score 2):

In general yes: That's what [`for`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/for) or [`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/foreach-in) loops are for. (Linq is just a shorthand for these)

---

In your code snippet it looks like you want to have one index where the value is `false` instead so you could use e.g.

```
public GameObject[] LockPIButtons;

public void SetInactive(int index)
{
    for(var i = 0; i < LockPIButtons.Length; i++)
    {
        lockPIButton.SetActive(i != index);
    }
}
```

so calling it like

```
SetInactive(0);
```

would result in what you showed us.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to clarify that I'm using UnityEngine. after I read the loop suggestions, i came up with these solution

```
public GameObject[] LockPIButton;

for (var T = 0; T < LockPIButton.Length; T++) { LockPIButton[T].SetActive(true); }
//This one is to make sure all elements is (true)

LockPIButton[0].SetActive(false);
//This one is added because i want to make an exception on 1 single element, so i change it back to (false).
```